# Screen saver/screen blanking never invoked after time, forcing screen off only temporary

Tags: windows-10, power, screensaver

I have a Windows 10 machine on a baremetal desktop that for reasons unclear refuses to turn off its screens (or activate a screen saver). Even with aggressive timing (i.e. 1 minute), it refuses to take action. If I force the screen off (i.e. I map the power button to "Force Screen Off" in the power settings), it will turn off temporarily, but come right back after only a few seconds.

I've tried a few things, including removing most of my peripherals and running commands such as **powercfg -energy** to attempt to diagnose it, but aside from a few peripherals that refuse to engage Selective Suspend, the report has no real surprises. I'm not sure what else may be at fault. If I place the entire computer into sleep mode, it fully goes to sleep until I wake it up.

I have multiple monitors, but this behavior persists whether I have only one active or both.

Comment: Something is turning it right back on, can you check your task scheduler or what else is running in the task manager. Also please scan for viruses and use the button on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding that I had an old wireless joystick receiver plugged in, which apparently did something to the input periodically that I couldn't see (or perhaps it was the driver). Either way, once I removed it, the issue stopped.